# nginx virtual hosting working locally but not globally

Tags: nginx, hosting, virtual

When i use curl on localhost its work .

```
root@ip-10-87-3-236:/etc/nginx# curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" http://localhost/ib

Output :

200
```

But when  i connect to browser through internet i am getting

```
Not Found
The requested resource was not found on this server.
```

nginx config :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location /ib {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #whatever port your app runs on
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    
}
```

Please help here or share any doc that may be very helpful

thanks

Comment: Able to curl http://localhost/ib it will give 200

but http://127.0.0.1/ib 
Output 
`
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested resource was not found on this server.</p>
</body>
</html>
`
not able to understand  Please help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified `localhost` as your `server_name`. If you want to make this work over the internet and / or with your domainname of choise e.g `example.com` set the `server_name` to the domainname. This will fix your issue.

Reference: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name